# Adding new column to spark dataframe by getting data lookup from other dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to join 2 dataframes using pyspark, where data frame1 has multiple records of data from look up dataframe.

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 4, 'date_from,date_to'),(1, 8, 'emp_name')], ['col1', 'col2', 'error_cloumn'])
>>> df.show()

+---+--+------+-------------------+
|  col1|  col2|  error_cloumn     |
+---+--+------+-------------------+
|  1   |     4|  date_from,date_to|
|  1   |     8|       emp_name    |
+---+--+------+-------------------+


>>> look_up_df = spark.createDataFrame([('date_from','DD-MM-YY', ' text msg1'),('date_to', 'DD-MM-YY', 'test msg2'),('emp_name', 'VARCHAR(100)', 'test msg3'),('emp_type', 'VARCHAR(100)', 'test msg4')], ['column_nm', 'clmn1', 'comment'])
>>> look_up_df.show()

+---+--+------+--------------------------+
| 'column_nm'|'clmn1'       |'comment'     |
+---+--+------+--------------------------+
|'date_from' |'DD-MM-YY'    | 'text msg1'|
| 'date_to'  |'DD-MM-YY'    | 'test msg2'|
| 'emp_name' |'VARCHAR(100)'| 'test msg3'|
| 'emp_type' |'VARCHAR(100)'| 'test msg4'|
+---+--+------+--------------------------+


Expected output : error_desc as look_up_df[column_nm] + lit('expected') + look_up_df[clmn1]+ lit('and comment is') + look_up_df[comment]
output_df:
+---+--+------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-
|  col1|  col2|  error_cloumn     | error_desc                                                                                                      |
+---+--+------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-
|  1   |     4|  date_from,date_to|date_from expected as DD-MM-YY  and comment is text msg1, date_to expected as DD-MM-YY  and comment is text msg2 |
|  1   |     8|       emp_name    |emp_name should be VARCHAR(100) and comment is test msg3                                                         |
+---+--+------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-
```

I am trying using blow code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 4, 'date_from,date_to'),(1, 8, 'emp_name')], ['col1', 'col2', 'error_cloumn'])
df.show()

look_up_df = spark.createDataFrame([('date_from','DD-MM-YY', ' text msg1'),('date_to', 'DD-MM-YY', 'test msg2'),('emp_name', 'VARCHAR(100)', 'test msg3'),('emp_type', 'VARCHAR(100)', 'test msg4')], ['column_nm', 'clmn1', 'comment'])
look_up_df.show()

output_df = df.join(look_up_df, df["error_cloumn"] == look_up_df["column_nm"]).withColumn("error_desc",F.concat(F.Col('column_nm'),F.lit(' expected as '),F.Col('clmn1').lit(' and comment is '),.Col('comment'),))
```

This code working for one record, but failing for multiple columns like date_from,date_to in records

Comment: The answer you accepted does not provide the true solution as for 'emp_name' the error_desc should be different. The solution shared by me cover that. Consider changing the accepted answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what you're looking for is quite straightforward, just multiple steps and could be a bit confusing if you don't write it properly. You might find this answer is basically as similar as the other, but with better structure. I added comments on each step, but feel free to run each of them to follow the logic.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('error_column', F.explode(F.split('error_column', ','))) # breakdown multiple errors to different rows
    .join(look_up_df.withColumnRenamed('column_nm', 'error_column'), on=['error_column'], how='inner') # rename column so we can shorten the `on` conditions
    .withColumn('error_desc', F.concat( # concat as your requirement
        F.col('error_column'),
        F.lit(' expected '),
        F.col('clmn1'),
        F.lit(' and comment is '),
        F.col('comment'),
    ))
    .groupBy('col1', 'col2') # as we broken it down, it's time to join them back together
    .agg(
        F.concat_ws(', ', F.collect_list('error_column')).alias('error_column'), # concat errors together with comma separated
        F.concat_ws(', ', F.collect_list('error_desc')).alias('error_desc'), # concat descriotions together with comma separated
    )
    .show(10, False)
)

+----+----+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col1|col2|error_column      |error_desc                                                                                               |
+----+----+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1   |4   |date_from, date_to|date_from expected DD-MM-YY and comment is  text msg1, date_to expected DD-MM-YY and comment is test msg2|
|1   |8   |emp_name          |emp_name expected VARCHAR(100) and comment is test msg3                                                  |
+----+----+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest splitting `error_cloumn` in `df`, exploding (both contained in `pyspark.sql.functions` module) and then joining. You would get multiple rows and, grouping by `col1, col2` (assuming those could be the grouping keys), you could aggregate text in the way you presented in the results.

Please let me know if you need more support on that

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, lit, expr, when, explode, split, collect_list, concat_ws

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 4, 'date_from,date_to'),(1, 8, 'emp_name')], ['col1', 'col2', 'error_column'])
df = df.withColumn('all_values',explode(split('error_column',',')))
df.show()

look_up_df = spark.createDataFrame([('date_from','DD-MM-YY', ' text_msg1'),('date_to', 'DD-MM-YY', 'test_msg2'),('emp_name', 'VARCHAR(100)', 'test_msg3'),('emp_type', 'VARCHAR(100)', 'test_msg4')], ['column_name', 'clmn1', 'comment'])
look_up_df = (
  look_up_df.withColumn('msg', 
                        when(look_up_df.column_name.like('%date%'),concat(look_up_df.column_name,lit(' expected as '),look_up_df.clmn1, lit('  and comment is '), look_up_df.comment))
                        .otherwise(concat(look_up_df.column_name,lit(' should be '),look_up_df.clmn1, lit('  and comment is '), look_up_df.comment)) )
)
display(look_up_df)


result = df.join(look_up_df,df.all_values == look_up_df.column_name , how = 'inner').groupby('col1','col2', 'error_column').agg(collect_list('msg').alias('final_msg')).withColumn('final_msg2',concat_ws(',','final_msg'))

display(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, error_desc is one column, and look_up_df.column_name.like('%date%') is taking all similar fields right?

Comment: @KSoumya Yes you are correct like '%date%' will take care of the values that will be having date in it and error_desc  col will be 'final_msg2' in my code above.